# Finding highest mean in CSV file

Tags: python, csv, sorting, average

So, I have a csv file as follows: [Smaller Sample]

```
value,variable
320,1
272,1
284,1
544,2
568,2
544,2
316,3
558,3
542,3
260,4
266,4
710,4
272,5
290,5
558,5
416,6
782,6
626,6
```

My goal is to find the highest average, of each grouping. So, in this case, grouping `6` is the highest. With this information, I'd then make a new column that compares grouping `6` to all others.
Like so:

```
320,1,1
272,1,1
284,1,1
544,2,1
568,2,1
544,2,1
316,3,1
558,3,1
542,3,1
260,4,1
266,4,1
710,4,1
272,5,1
290,5,1
558,5,1
416,6,9
782,6,9
626,6,9
```

I have absolutely no idea where to start. I initially thought maybe I should split each line into a dictionary, then average each grouping, make a new key as the average, then take all of the keys[averaged groupings] and detect which is the highest. I'm just not sure how I'd put it back into CSV, or even execute this while keeping the integrity of the data.

Comment: How are `9` and `1` derived as the sole values for the third column? Can you clarify your comparison approach?

Comment: They're arbitrary values, they're only there to differentiate between grouping, ```1```,```2```, ```3```,```4```,```5``` vs ```6```. Because ```6``` has the highest average of all of the groupings. If you need anymore clarification, please let me know.

Comment: I don't understand either how you calculate the third column. Can you give an example of how you compare group 6 vs the others?

Comment: In essence, the third column is an identifier of which group has the highest average. Perhaps using ```1```, and ```9``` wasn't the best way to present my problem, but the goal is to have a third column that differentiates between the highest average of a group, vs the rest.

Comment: By grouping, I mean the second column. It has an identifier between 1 through 6 to present different datasets. E.g in this example, grouping ```1``` has values of ```320,272,284```

Comment: Here's example that would pertain to my issue, and relevant dataset; Grouping ```1``` has a has a mean of ```292```.  ```2``` has a mean of ```552```. ```3``` has a mean of ```472```. ```4``` has a mean of ```412```. ```5``` has a mean of ```373```. ```6``` has a mean of ```608```. Grouping ```6``` has the highest mean of all of the groups, so make a new column that differentiates between the rest of the groups, vs grouping ```6```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this kind of things, I would advise to use the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) package:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read your file
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

# Get the group means
group_means = data.groupby('variable')['value'].agg('mean') 

# Get the group with highest mean
group_max = group_means.idxmax()

# Add the last column to differentiate the highest mean
data['comparison'] = (data['variable'] == group_max).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools, csv
_h, *data = csv.reader(open('filename.csv'))
new_data = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x:x[-1])]
_max = max(new_data, key=lambda x:sum(a for a, _ in x[-1])/float(len(x[-1])))[0]
with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
  write = csv.writer(f)
  write.writerows([_h, *[[a, b, 9 if b == _max else 1] for a, b in data]])
```

Output:

```
value,variable
320,1,1
272,1,1
284,1,1
544,2,1
568,2,1
544,2,1
316,3,1
558,3,1
542,3,1
260,4,1
266,4,1
710,4,1
272,5,1
290,5,1
558,5,1
416,6,9
782,6,9
626,6,9
```